# simulator tablet in window 8

Tags: windows, simulator

I am developer in window 8 metro style app, but I can't find the way to simulate shake the tablet, turn around, turn left turn right, ... 
Does it have these simulated actions or not? In simulator VS 2012 express for window 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simulator can be rotated or flipped to see how your app behaves when a user changes the orientation of the screen. This comes in handy if you want to test such an app to see if it is correctly optimized for the portrait mode and the landscape mode. The simulator doesn’t eliminate the need to fully verify the app on physical devices, because it doesn’t simulate all the accelerometer sensitive capabilities such as tilt, but it will save you a lot of time in exposing potential problems in your app’s response to the changing of the orientation of the displaying device.

Available also in the VS 2012 express.

[image: You can test how the design change in portrait or landscape mode by clicking on these buttons]

Comment: Yes, you are right. We need physical device to test shaking action.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it exists in the express of VS 2012 but there are two little 3/4 circle arrow button on the side of the windows simulator that I have with the full VS 2012.  They will rotate the tablet to the left or right 90 degrees.